# Is it possible to make work together Django Rest Framework, + Django Channels + Reactjs? if so..do I need Socket.io too on the client side?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, socket.io, django-channels

I guess that the Title is quite explicit, but I will try to further explain my requirements so maybe anybody can help.

As explained Im building a site that uses DRF as backend  and React in the client side, and i would like to have some real time functionalities, so I´ve been researching on the issue which took me to Channels as the way to manage asyncronous actions and websockets. The question is that the more I read the more I get confused... by the Channels documentation one might say that it has capabilities to work whether sincronous as asyncronous server..but then i do not want to miss my DRF classes that simplify my life so much... and the there is this other question coming to my mind regarding if then, i must also use socket.io in the front to connect with channels on the back.... so as you see... im quite confused...anybody could help?

Comment: Example repo https://github.com/pplonski/simple-tasks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the client-side and socketio. but yes you can use Django channels and react to communicate on a WebSocket. you also be able to send a message on channels outside of consumers(API view). but it's kind of risky to retrieve data from WebSocket outside of the consumer. everything in consumers(channels) execute asynchronously so accessing received a message on WebSocket by API is not guaranteed.

1 - set up a Django-channels consumer and on connect add the channel to a group
2 - connect to the channel by react and communicate with the server and keep the channel open.
3- make APIs for events and send the event from API to the channel group.